# Selecting an element from an array from the keyboard

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to have an `array` with days of the week and then have a user input a number from the keyboard and then display the day that number matches. ie 5 would return friday.
The issue I'm having is taking the user input to tell it which element to print out. I have a feeling it's similar to the issue I had yesterday with swapping but can't see how to make it work as that one had the temp locations for moving the elements around. here's what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String []args)
   {
       Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] days = new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}; 
      int number, i=0;

      System.out.print ("Enter the number of the day you want: ");
      number = keyboardIn.nextInt();
      for (i= 0; i < days.length;)
      {
       if (number<= days.length)
       {
            System.out.print (days[i]);
       }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the index you can get the day of the week using `days[index]`. Something like this:

```
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] days = new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}; 

System.out.print ("Enter the number of the day you want: ");
int number = keyboardIn.nextInt()-1;
if (number<days.length && number>=0){
    System.out.println(days[number]);
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid number of day of the week");
}
```

I subtracted 1 since arrays start with 0. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Ant695 No problem. :) Feel free to accept my answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Ant695 added some error handling for index out of range.